# laravel backpack: how to use tooltip in datatables cells?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I override show.blade.php to have a button with a tooltip

```
<a href="{{ url($crud->route.'/'.$entry->getKey().'/show') }}"
   class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
   data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{ trans('backpack::crud.preview') }}"
>
    <i class="la la-eye"></i>
</a>
```

But this do not works. I think because datatable is loaded on ajax and/or tooltip is not initialized anywhere

Where should I do this sort of "auto init" of tooltip ?

More general question:

> how to simply override backpack for laravel's crud blades, for example for simply adding some custom js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add my own solution that also resolves a common and basic problem:

> how to simply override backpack for laravel's crud blades, for example for simply adding some custom js?

In the `setup()` method of my `UsersCrudController` I added thesse to use customized views

```
    $this->crud->setCreateView('anagraphics.users.create');
    $this->crud->setEditView('anagraphics.users.edit');
```

Then to *override without publishing and without copy/paste* I created

- resources/views/anagraphics/users/create.blade.php
- resources/views/anagraphics/users/edit.blade.php

Then in `create.blade.php`:

```
@extends('crud::create')

@push('after_scripts')
<script type="application/javascript">
  
</script>
@endpush
```

And in `edit.blade.php`:

```
@extends('crud::edit')

@push('after_scripts')
<script type="application/javascript">
  
</script>
@endpush
```

I suggest to document that you can extends original blade using

```
@extends('crud::<operation_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you execute this from the browser console after the table has loaded?

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```